# How to make font size responsive in React Native using NativeWind

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

I need to make text phrase to be fit in one line by using nativewind based on height and width of the screen
here is my code

`<Text className="text-base md:text-xl">Agree to our Terms and Privacy Policy </Text>`

I tried to add custome size to nativewind  by depending on height and width of the screen but didn't work with me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the combination of [numberOfLines](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#numberoflines) and [adjustsFontSizeToFit](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#adjustsfontsizetofit) to fit a text in the one line. Something like this:

```js
<Text numberOfLines={1} adjustsFontSizeToFit={true} ...>
  Agree to our Terms and Privacy Policy
</Text>
```